# CustomUI ribbon customization disappears on save?

Tags: excel, ribbon

I've created an Excel workbook for a client of mine which uses a custom ribbon tab to access the VBA functionality.  It thus contains a customUI.xml file with the extra ribbon code in it (by using the Custom UI Editor tool).  By now, all was working well for over a year.

However, a few days ago the ribbon customizations keep disappearing after he makes a simple modification to the file and saves it again.  Nothing fancy; just change some cell values and ctrl-s save.  When opening the saved version the ribbon doesn't show up, and on closer inspection it turns out the ribbon customization is completely gone from the file at that point (the entire root customUI folder is gone and the reference to it from the _rels.rels file is gone too).  He's just a regular Excel user, so he doesn't even know about Office custom UI ribbon xmls etc, so it's not that he has been messing with tools he shouldn't have messed with.  When I open a working copy of the file on my machine and save it, the ribbon remains in place.

The VBA is still intact though, and the listobject tables that are placed on some sheets are still there too, so it can't be because it got intermediately saved in 2003 format or such...

The file does live in a Sharepoint and OneDrive environment, but IIRC he also had this problem when retrieving a working backup of the file, placing it on his desktop and making a modification from there.  Then again a few months ago his IT administrator has moved his company over to Office 356 and migrated his files to the cloud, so it might well be his desktop is on OneDrive too.

What could cause a perfectly fine ribbon to disappear like that?  A rogue Office update?  Or some Sharepoint 'security' feature to remove ribbons on save? (note that I'm not well known with Sharepoint so this is just wild speculation.)  He's using Office 365, so I presume he's on Excel 2019 (as am I).

All leads are welcome, because I'm at a total loss here...

Comment: Was the document opened and saved in Word online?

Comment: Good point; could well be.  I'll inform.  But would that strip any ribbon customizations from Office files?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev: I've gotten an answer, but he doesn't touch hte online part of Office; he solely works from Windows Explorer and the desktop versions of the Office apps.  So the mystery is still unsolved...